# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a typescript class that has an array item podetails.

```
POheader class:
import { POdetail } from './podetail';

export class POheader {
  public PO_Number: string;
  public podetails: [POdetail];
  constructor(
  ) {
  }
}
```

I initialized it:

```
poheader: POheader = new POheader();
```

but when I push it gives this error.

this is the push statement:

```
this.poheader.podetails.push({
  Item: this.NewItem,
  description: this.NewDescription
});
```

error:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Comment: Evidently `this.poheader.podetails` is undefined. It doesn't look like you initialize either of the members of `Poheader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before pushing data into podetails initialize with empty array.

public podetails: [POdetail];

change to

public podetails: POdetail[] = [];